# 500 error while calling azure services from phonegap

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-cordova

I have two projects on local system, One for web api services and other for Cordova phonegap ui. For testing purpose I am running both project at same time, and use url of service project in phonegap app to call services and all things are working fine. I am using sql server database.

Now, I added only my database on Microsoft azure and I am using azure database connection string in my web api project on local system, and still everything is working fine, I am able to store data on azure database.

Now, I added my web api too on azure and now I am using server api service url in my cordova app for calling services of azure. but it is giving me 500 error with

```
message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

What I need to change to call my published web services of azure from my local phonegap application ?

Comment: I am not sure this is cordova related. But this error typically happens when you are using the wrong SQL server connection string or the Azure SQL server firewall is blocking your client IP address.

Comment: I guess I need to change something in services or cordova app. Because services are not getting called from app.